# awk script to add numbers in one column

Tags: awk

How can I add (numbers on the 2nd column) using `for` or `while` loops in an `awk` script?

While  numbers at `$1` are random and in increasing order:

- 1 through 2 in first iteration,
- 1.1 through 2.1 in 2nd iteration,
- 1.2 through 2.2 in 3rd iteration,
- 1.3 through 2.3 in 4th iteration
- ... up to the end

That means with 0.1 increment at each iteration.

#### Expected output:

- 39 for 1st iteration
- 47 for 2nd iteration...

#### Input data:

```
1.0  1
1.1  3
1.2  4
1.3  3
1.4  5
1.5  7
1.6  10
2.0  6
2.1  9
2.2  2
2.3  8
2.4  0
3.0  4
3.2  5
4.0  8
4.1  6
5.0  7
6.0  6
7.0  7
8.7  9
9.8  2
```

Comment: And your sample code is...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. +1 for a carefully described problem with input and desired output.  But it would be good if you showed what you had tried.

Comment: It's not clear to me how the iterations go. If you sum the values for 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ... 2.0 it's not 39. The sum for 1.0, 2.0, 3.0,... 7.0 is 39 but then the rest doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @tripleee: the sum for the range 1.0-2.0 is 1+3+4+3+5+7+10+6 = 39.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I multiply each $1 by 10 to avoid [problems with imprecise decimal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems).

```
awk -v max=$(tail -1 data | awk '{print $1*10}') '
    {n = $1 * 10}
    NR==1 {min = n}
    { 
        for (i=min; i<=(max-10); i++) {
            if (i <= n && n <= (i+10)) {
                sum[i, i+10] += $2
            }
        }
    }
    END {
        for (key in sum) {
            split(key, a, SUBSEP)
            printf "[%.1f,%.1f] = %d\n", a[1]/10, a[2]/10, sum[key]
        }
    }
' data | sort -n
```

output

```
[1.0,2.0] = 39
[1.1,2.1] = 47
[1.2,2.2] = 46
[1.3,2.3] = 50
...
[8.6,9.6] = 9
[8.7,9.7] = 9
[8.8,9.8] = 2
```

Comment: am sorry to ask this, how can I run this code..I have to save it in separate file and run  or use it directly on command line...I am newbie to awk thats the reason

Comment: Put all the above into a file named "accumulate.sh" (or something). Make sure the first line of the script is "#!/bin/sh". Make the file executable: `chmod a+x accumulate.sh`. Invoke it with `/path/to/accumulate.sh` or move it to a directory that's in your `$PATH` and invoke it with `accumulate.sh`